# regex not detecting period and digit

Tags: python, regex

I read about regex at https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/regular-expressions-the-last-guide-6800283ac034 but am having trouble trying to do something very simple.

```
s = re.compile('(norm|conv)[.][0-9]')

for k,v in densenet_state_dict.items():
    print(k)
    print(s.findall(k))
```

It is supposed to print something like `norm.2` but it is only detecting norm or conv in my output, not the period nor the digit.

```
module.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.norm.2.running_mean
['norm']
module.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.norm.2.running_var
['norm']
```

I even tried `'(norm|conv)\.[0-9]'`. Am i missing something very important?

---

EDIT: The minimum working example

```
module_type = re.compile('(norm|conv)\.[0-9]')
module_name = "module.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.conv.2.weight"
print(module_name)
print(module_type.findall(module_name))
```

prints

```
module.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.conv.2.weight
['conv']
```

Comment: This could use some additional clarification. What is `densenet_state_dict`? If it has nothing to do with the problem, I suggest removing it to produce a [mcve]. BTW, your second attempt looks pretty good--that should work!

Comment: Well your second try with `(norm|conv)\.[0-9]` is the correct regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second regex looks good. If it's not capturing what you want, try:

```
r'((?:norm|conv)\.[0-9])'
```

to capture the entire thing (`?:` is a non-capturing group). Here's an example:

```
import re

s = """module.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.norm.2.running_mean
['norm']
module.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.norm.2.running_var
['norm']
"""

print(re.findall(r'((?:norm|conv)\.[0-9])', s)) # => ['norm.2', 'norm.2']
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression might simply extract our desired outputs with a capturing group:

```
(norm\.[0-9]+|conv\.[0-9]+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AANXAp/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(norm\.[0-9]+|conv\.[0-9]+)"

test_str = ("module.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.norm.2.running_mean\n"
    "module.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.norm.2.running_var\n"
    "module.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.conv.2121.running_mean\n"
    "module.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.conv.21341.running_var")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]